# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código y me arroja el siguiente error.

```
def hipAsiatico(L_colegios,L_percentAsian,L_mathScore):
    perAsiancollege=[]
    listpromMath=[]
    pernoAsiancollege=[]
    lpromMathnoAsian=[]
    for percent in L_percentAsian:
        val= float(percent.replace("%", ""))
        if val >= 30:
            pos=L_percentAsian.index(percent)
            colegio=L_colegios[pos]
            promMath=L_mathScore[pos]
            perAsiancollege.append(colegio)
            listpromMath.append(promMath)
        else:
            pos=L_percentAsian.index(percent)
            colegio=L_colegios[pos]
            promMath=L_mathScore[pos]
            pernoAsiancollege.append(colegio)
            lpromMathnoAsian.append(promMath)
    contador1=0
    for nota in listpromMath:
        contador1 += int(nota)
    promColconAsiaticos= (contador1/len(listpromMath)).__round__(2)
    contador2=0
    for nota in lpromMathnoAsian:
        contador2 += int(nota)
    promColsinAsiaticos=(contador2/len(lpromMathnoAsian)).__round__(2)
    print("Promedio de Colegios con mas 30% Estudaiantes asiaticos: ", promColconAsiaticos)
    print("Resto de Colegios:",promColsinAsiaticos)
    if promColconAsiaticos > promColsinAsiaticos:
        print("Hipostesis correcta!")
    else:
        print("Hipostesis Incorrecta!")
```

Al parecer tengo todo correcto pero al momento de poner los valores me arroja un mensaje `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Adicional a esto la consola me arroja el siguiente error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\SISTEMAS\Desktop\Proyecto.py", line 218, in <module>
    resHip = hipAsiatico(resColegio,x1,x2)
   File "C:\Users\SISTEMAS\Desktop\Proyecto.py", line 135, in hipAsiatico
    for percent in L_percentAsian:
 TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: ¿ Con que valores estás llamando a tu función `hipAsiatico( )` ? Porque el mensaje indica que le estás pasando un `float` como segundo argumento, `L_percentAsian`.

Comment: Le estoy ingresando 2 valores al azar te tipo float --> 5.6 y 6.2 pero al momento de realizar el ingreso me arroja el mensaje que describe , que podría estar realizando erróneamente?

Comment: Claramente, un `float` **no es una lista** ni nada *iterable*. Eso es lo que te está diciendo el error: `for percent in L_percentAsian:`. Estás intentando recorrer un float, cosa imposible.

Comment: Lo que hice orita , es enviar directamente los valores cargados en el metodo y ahora me sale un error Exception has occurred: ZeroDivisionError
division by zero
  File "C:\Users\SISTEMAS\Desktop\Proyecto.py", line 152, in hipAsiatico
    promColconAsiaticos= (contador1/len(listpromMath)).__round__(2) que podría estar erróneo?